# Building Azure Deployment Package from Eclipse fails

Tags: deployment, azure, eclipse-plugin, cloud, azure-configuration

I just created a simple java project using Eclipse following the steps on the Microsoft Website http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690944.aspx.

When I click finish on the "Windows Azure Deployment Project" dialog I get the following error dialog box.

**Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Windows Azure Dependency Builder' on project 'AzureSample'.
java.lang.NullPointerException**

I'm using jdk7 and Tomcat 7.

Can anyone advice on what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I think the issue stems from a missing/corrupt item in the Components section ( Windows Azure Role -> Components).
I'm not sure because I can't reproduce it. I removed my deployment project and started Eclipse (solves problems more often then it should).

What I did change however is that I pointed the Tomcat 7 to a freshly downloaded and extracted zip. 
I deleted the first deployment project (that was throwing the error you described) and started over. 
Then I did the following:
1. download apache-tomcat-7.0.39 64bit Tomcat zip file.
2. unzip to directory 
3. Windows Azure Role -> Server Configuration -> Server 
     set "locally" to the directory in step 2.

A symptom I had which went away too was that in Components ( Windows Azure Role -> Components)
if I clicked on anything it would throw an error...and I was clicking there because there was an empty import in the middle of the list.